Styling of native date picker on Android
We have following issue:

We use an inApp browser to render a website to onboard a customer
We have an input field with type="date". Clicking this field renders the usual device-dependent date picker view
On Android devices we realized, that the date picker is going to a dark mode and the UX gets disturbed (see screenshot).

Is there any way of how to control the styling of the date picker?
Screenshot from Android device with normal (non dark mode) settings
We tried to implement an input type="date" field and expect a date picker which is correctly styled

so it's a web issue then. Maybe you can update the style on the input date with color-scheme

but how is this overlay etc deciding on color, this grey overlay is introduced once you clicked the input field. the page itself is white

have you tried updated the color-scheme on calendar element? i will post my answer to that.

I think it's a web issue, try using color-scheme to the input?


.input-date {
  color-scheme: light;
}
<input type="date" class="input-date" />



